# Remove XML element from file using SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml, laravel, simplexml

I am pulling in XML data from an external source, this file needs to be edited based on ID existence in the database, I am having problems removing the node if it shouldn't be returned.

Here is the XML structure before any editing.

```
<Document>
  <Placemark>
    <name> name </name>
    <address> address </address>
    <description></description>
    <timestamp>
       <when>2016-06-20T13:56:00-04:00</when>
    </timestamp>
    <styleurl>#asset1234</styleurl>
    <point>
        <coordinates>28.006725,-20.353084,2320</coordinates>
    </point>
  </Placemark>
</Document>
```

Here is what I am currently doing in my code:

```
$url = "www.api.com/GetData"; // This return the XML contents
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($contents);

foreach ($xml->Document->Placemark as $placemark) {
    $id = str_replace(['#', 'asset'], '', $placemark->styleUrl);
    $tracker = $company->GsatTrackers()->where('tracker_id', $id)->first();

    if (!$tracker) {
        // Remove the placemark
    }
}
```

It iterates through the data fine but removing the node is the problem, I have tried removing it a few ways at the position specified above:

```
unset($placemark); // Does nothing.

unset($placemark[0]); // Throws error when continuing the foreach: element no longer exists.

$dom = dom_import_simplexml($placemark);
$dom->parentNode->removeChild($dom); // This works for the first one in the foreach loop but breaks the loop.
```

Is there any way to do this? or is there a better all around solution to what I am trying to accomplish?

Comment: https://eval.in/598376

Comment: @splash58 Hi, thanks for the answer, it worked your way, all I needed to adjust was when you call the unset() you also need to minus one from $i, otherwise the loop messes up.

Comment: forgot. Usually i make loop from high to low in such cases. But now i only thought to show you an approach